# Convert python struct.pack to C#

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to convert the following python code to C#

```
sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('I', len(message)))
sys.stdout.write(message)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I need the C# program to output to console. Tried the following, but the C# and python programs don't output the same - the struct.pack part seems messed up.

```
Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
stdout.WriteByte((byte)message.Length);
Console.Write(message);
```

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the struct.pack outputs 3 additional null characters, which messed up the results.

Here is the code that worked:

```
Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
stdout.WriteByte((byte)message.Length);
stdout.WriteByte((byte)'\0');
stdout.WriteByte((byte)'\0');
stdout.WriteByte((byte)'\0');
Console.Write(message);
```

Ugly, but does the job :)